# Apply Babel plugin to specific directory

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I am using a Babel transform plugin for my React Native application, but I am wanting to it to apply only to particular directories.

The transform is to allow me to code in a convenient DSL, but as such will encounter errors if exposed to regular javascript. It's not a plugin I've written myself, so I am not able to modify it's behavior without manually including my own fork. Instead, I am wanting to simply specify in `.babelrc` where it should or should not be enabled to transform the AST.

Is there a way to do this? Such as a plugin option handled by Babel itself?

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": [
      ["some_plugin", {
           include: ["./plugin_specific_code"]
      }]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about `.bablerc` (try and see if it works) but you can definitely create a `package.json` in any given directory and override the main package.json settings for babel as follows:

**/package.json**

I only want the `flow` preset for my normal builds as defined by my main package.json.

```
{
  ...
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "flow"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
      "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ],
    "env": {
      "test": {
        "plugins": [
          "istanbul"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "nyc": {
    "require": [
      "babel-register"
    ],
    "reporter": [
      "lcov",
      "text"
    ],
    "sourceMap": false,
    "instrument": false
  }
}
```

---

**/tests/package.json**

For unit/integation tests I need more presets so my code is transformed into a format that mocha/nyc/instanbul can understand so I define those in a package.json in that directory.

```
{
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2017",
      "flow",
      "stage-0"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
      "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `.babelrc` should work too: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/#lookup-behavior.